# grid-column-end breaks repeat(auto-fit)

Tags: html, css

I have an unknown amount of columns which I want to justify over the entire screen using CSS grid.

CSS Grid `repeat(auto-fit` does exactly that as you can see in this demo:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(80px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(20px, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="background:yellow">Entry 1</li>
  <li style="background:dodgerblue">Entry 2</li>
  <li style="background:tomato">Entry 3</li>
  <li style="background:limegreen">Entry 4</li>
</ul>
```

[image: 4 columns with auto-fit spread to the full width]

It also works great for multiple columns as it will alway ensure that the first row is filled with columns:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(80px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(20px, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="background:yellow">Entry 1</li>
  <li style="background:dodgerblue">Entry 2</li>
  <li style="background:tomato">Entry 3</li>
  <li style="background:limegreen">Entry 4</li>
  <li style="background:yellow">Entry 5</li>
  <li style="background:dodgerblue">Entry 6</li>
  <li style="background:tomato">Entry 7</li>
  <li style="background:limegreen">Entry 8</li>
  <li style="background:yellow">Entry 9</li>
  <li style="background:dodgerblue">Entry 10</li>
  <li style="background:tomato">Entry 11</li>
</ul>
```

Now comes the part where I am struggling.

In addition to those columns I want a special second row which spans over the full width of the container.
According to the spec of `grid-column-start` `grid-column-end` it should be possible:

> If a negative integer is given, it instead counts in reverse, starting from the end edge of the explicit grid.

```
:after {
  content: '';
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: -1;
  background: yellow;
}
```

It works as expected when there are enough items to fill up the entire first row:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(80px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(20px, 1fr);
}

ul:after {
  content: '';
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: -1;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="background:yellow">Entry 1</li>
  <li style="background:dodgerblue">Entry 2</li>
  <li style="background:tomato">Entry 3</li>
  <li style="background:limegreen">Entry 4</li>
  <li style="background:yellow">Entry 5</li>
  <li style="background:dodgerblue">Entry 6</li>
  <li style="background:tomato">Entry 7</li>
  <li style="background:limegreen">Entry 8</li>
  <li style="background:yellow">Entry 9</li>
  <li style="background:dodgerblue">Entry 10</li>
  <li style="background:tomato">Entry 11</li>
  <li style="background:limegreen">Entry 12</li>
</ul>
```

However it breaks the case with less items.
Suddenly `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(80px, 1fr));` will no longer fill up the first row anymore. Instead the columns in the first row are resized to their minimal width:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(80px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(20px, 1fr);
}

ul:after {
  content: '';
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: -1;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="background:yellow">Entry 1</li>
  <li style="background:dodgerblue">Entry 2</li>
  <li style="background:tomato">Entry 3</li>
  <li style="background:limegreen">Entry 4</li>
</ul>
```

[image: Larger Window]

Is there any way to span a row about all columns and still prevent a whitespace in the first row?

Here is an image of what I would expect it to look like:

[image: Expected behaviour without a whitespace in the first row]

Comment: you will always have one row of columns or it can be many rows?

Comment: Thanks - I'll added more examples and what I am trying to achieve - I hope it helps to understand the question better

Comment: I understand but you will always have one row of elements or you can have more elements that will wrap to the next row? because if it's for one row, I have a solution

Comment: It can have multiple rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one of the options, you can use the classic combination of `position: relative;` + `position: absolute;`. This is a rather specific solution that will only work in *certain cases*. You can see some examples of implementation below:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(80px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(20px, 1fr);
  position: relative;
}

ul:after {
  content: 'your service line';
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1rem; /* pay attention to the fixed height */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="background:yellow">Entry 1</li>
  <li style="background:dodgerblue">Entry 2</li>
  <li style="background:tomato">Entry 3</li>
  <li style="background:limegreen">Entry 4</li>
</ul>
```

But at the same time there is a problem with the row height, which *can* sometimes be solved through [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables):

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(80px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(var(--service-height), 1fr);
  position: relative;
  --service-height: 2rem; /* example of height passing via CSS variables */
}

ul:after {
  content: 'your service line';
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--service-height); 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="background:yellow">Entry 1</li>
  <li style="background:dodgerblue">Entry 2</li>
  <li style="background:tomato">Entry 3</li>
  <li style="background:limegreen">Entry 4</li>
</ul>
```

However, in certain cases, this can work even in more complex cases, for example, if there are many rows:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(80px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(var(--service-height), 1fr);
  position: relative;
  --service-height: 2rem; 
}

ul:after {
  content: 'your service line #1';
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--service-height); /* pay attention to the fixed height */
}

ul:before {
  content: 'your service line 2';
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 1;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--service-height); /* pay attention to the fixed height */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="background:yellow">Entry 1</li>
  <li style="background:dodgerblue">Entry 2</li>
  <li style="background:tomato">Entry 3</li>
  <li style="background:limegreen">Entry 4</li>
  
  <li style="background:pink; grid-row:3">Entry 5</li>
  <li style="background:lightgreen; grid-row:3">Entry 6</li>
  <li style="background:orange; grid-row:3">Entry 7</li>
</ul>
```

You can also use JS and CSS Variables to set a specific number of columns. In case of changes in the number of nested elements, you can recalculate via [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Example below:

```js
const recalc = (item) => {
  item.style.setProperty('--count', item.children.length);
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
  for (const mutation of mutations) {
    recalc(mutation.target);
  }
});

document.querySelectorAll('.fix').forEach((item) => {
  recalc(item);
  observer.observe(item, {
    childList: true
  });
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--count, 1), minmax(80px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(20px, 1fr);
  height: 200px;
}

ul:after {
  content: 'your service line';
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: -1;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="fix">
  <li style="background:yellow">Entry 1</li>
  <li style="background:dodgerblue">Entry 2</li>
  <li style="background:tomato">Entry 3</li>
  <li style="background:limegreen">Entry 4</li>
</ul>
```

Otherwise, you might be better turn your attention to [CSS Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex), which is probably better suited for this:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 200px;
}

ul li {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

ul:after {
  content: 'your service line';
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="background:yellow">Entry 1</li>
  <li style="background:dodgerblue">Entry 2</li>
  <li style="background:tomato">Entry 3</li>
  <li style="background:limegreen">Entry 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Really impressive ideas  
Unfortunately I have multiple limitations: 
I can't use JS calculations because of SSR & CLS.
I don't know how many columns fit in the first row.

Comment: position:absolute allowed me to build a work a round...